# Is this a normal fan speed and CPU temperature for an idle MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, cpu, temperature

Is this a normal fan speed and CPU temperature for an idle MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015). The fact that fan 2 is not spinning worries me. I can get 'loaded' fan speeds and temps if that would be helpful.

**--- CPU Stats ---**

CPU temp: 52.38°C

.

**--- Main Fan Stats ---**

Total fans in system: 2

Fan 0 speed: 2154.0 RPM

Fan 1 speed: **0.0 RPM**

.

**--- Other Temp Stats ---**

- TaSP Unknown  30.0°C
- Ta0P Unknown  30.13°C
- Th1H NB/CPU/GPU HeatPipe 1 Proximity  37.5°C
- Th2H Unknown  38.13°C
- Ts0P Palm rest L  26.0°C
- Ts0S Memory Bank Proximity  32.5°C
- Ts1P Unknown  24.63°C
- Ts1S Unknown  32.78°C
- TBXT Unknown  27.19°C
- TB0T Battery TS_MAX  27.19°C
- TB1T Battery 1  27.19°C
- TB2T Battery 2  27.19°C
- **TCGC PECI GPU  56.0°C**
- **TCSA PECI SA  61.0°C**
- **TCTD Unknown  -0.42°C**
- **TCXC PECI CPU  68.06°C**
- **TCXP Unknown  68.06°C**
- **TC0E CPU 0 ??  66.97°C**
- **TC0F CPU 0 ??  68.75°C**
- **TC0P CPU 0 Proximity  47.0°C**
- **TC1f Unknown  70.72°C**
- **TC1C Core 1  67.0°C**
- **TC1F Unknown  70.72°C**
- **TC2C Core 2  62.0°C**
- **TC3C Core 3  62.0°C**
- **TC4C Core 4  58.0°C**
- TG0D GPU 0 Die  35.0°C
- TG0F Unknown  35.0°C
- **TG0P GPU 0 Proximity  45.0°C**
- **TG1D GPU 1 Die  -127.0°C**
- TH0a Unknown  32.25°C
- TH0b Unknown  31.25°C
- TH0c Unknown  30.25°C
- **TH0x Unknown  -127.0°C**
- TH0A Unknown  32.25°C
- TH0B Unknown  31.25°C
- TH0C Unknown  30.25°C
- **TH0F Unknown  -53.75°C**
- **TH0R Unknown  -53.75°C**
- TH0V Unknown  31.08°C
- **TM0P Memory Slot Proximity  40.25°C**
- TM0S Memory Slot 1  37.64°C
- **TPCD Platform Controller Hub Die  44.0°C**
- **TP0P Unknown  40.13°C**
- TW0P AirPort Proximity  36.31°C

---

#### UPDATE

I sent the mac off to be fixed and it turned out to be something stuck in the right fan causing it to not move! Looking at my fan speeds now:
left: 3000rpm
right: 2800rpm (seems consistently slower so maybe slightly damaged :L)

CPU temp is now idle at: 48°C ish

Long story short if one of your fan's is around zero then its got stuck or has broken!

Comment: I've owned two rMBP models, and both always had both of fans spinning (lowest speed is ~2000 RPM). All of those temps look within standard range. I'd try running Apple Hardware test to make sure there isn't a problem with your fan (make sure it's not broken).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I sent the mac off to be fixed and it turned out to be something stuck in the right fan causing it to not move! Looking at my fan speeds now:
left: 3000rpm
right: 2800rpm (seems consistently slower so maybe slightly damaged :L)

CPU temp is now idle at: 48°C ish

Long story short if one of your fan's is around zero then its got stuck or has broken!

Answer (score 4):

The various temperature readings look absolutely 100% fine!

This [resource](https://www.intelmactemp.com/list) (which can be filtered) clearly shows that your CPU temp at 52.38°C is nothing to worry about.

My MBP temp is regularly between 66 and 81 degrees, and my fans are regularly at 6200 RPM when my CPU usage is high.

However, the fact that your stats indicate only one fan is spinning warrants further investigation. I would run an Apple Hardware Diagnostics to see if it finds any errors. To do this:

1. Fully shut down your MBP
2. Restart your MBP
3. Immediately press the <kbd>D</kbd> key and **keep it down** until you see the Diagnostics screen appear
4. Wait for Diagnostics to finish (this typically only takes a few minutes)
5. Once complete, one of two things will appear on the screen:

   - a *No issues found* message
   - a brief description of any errors found plus further instructions
6. If the diagnostics test does find errors, take a note of what they are

**Note:** If pressing and holding the <kbd>D</kbd> key at Step 3 doesn't work, start again at Step 1 and, at Step 3 press and hold both the <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> keys instead. This will try and run diagnostics from the internet instead, so you will need to allow more time for it to complete.

Let us know how you go.

Answer (score 1):

Macbook pro shut off temp is around 105 to 110C if I read correctly.
Also fans will favor silence over cooling in macbooks. So likely that second fan is not kicking in until it reaches something like 70C.

If over time you notice an upwards trend of temps, I'd look into cleaning the dust out and getting an application called Macs Fan Control to turn up the fan speeds based on temps. The downside is, the faster you run the fans, the sooner they will wear out.